# ElasticSearch: including nested fields in _all?

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I have documents that look like this:

```
{"foo" : "blah blah blah",
 "bar" : "bla bla bla",
 "baz" : [{"href" : "someid"}, {"href" : "otherid"}, ...],
 ... }
```

I want to do a search that finds all documents where `id` occurs in one of the `href` subdocuments. If I set `baz.href` to be unanalyzed in the mapping, I can search for `baz.href` with a term query just fine.

However, what I really want is to be able to search for this ID no matter where it occurs. It could be in `baz.href`, `quux.href`, or `whatever.href`. Searching in `_all` would be perfectly acceptable.

However, I just can't make this work. I never get any results, unless I search on exactly `baz.href`.

I tried setting `include_in_all` on `baz` in the mapping, to no avail. I tried setting it on `baz.href`, and that didn't work, either.

I know I could duplicate the IDs in a separate `all_hrefs` field in the top level, but that blows up the documents unnecessarily, and just seems ugly. The reference lists can be quite big. I could also parse my own mappings and find all the `href`s there, so that I could list all the `href` fields explicitly in the query, but as the data model grows that's eventually no longer going to scale.

Help?

**Update:** The mapping for the `datasets` field (and all other fields that contain `href`s looks like this):

```
"datasets" : {
   "properties" : {
      "href" : {
         "include_in_all" : true,
         "index" : "not_analyzed",
         "type" : "string"
      }
   },
   "type" : "nested"
},
```

I've tried with dropping the `nested`, and dropping the `include_in_all`, but it makes no difference. When I had `nested` I could use a nested query, but the `path` has to be set to `datasets` because `*` fails since not all fields contain nested objects.

Answer (score 0):

Using the supplied mapping:

```
$ curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/datasets/data?pretty=true' -d '
{
  "datasets" : {
    "properties" : {
      "href" : {
        "include_in_all" : false,
        "index" : "not_analyzed",
        "type" : "string"
      }
    },
    "type" : "nested"
  }
}'
```

When i indexed these documents:

```
$ curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/datasets/data' -d '
{
  "foo": "blah blah blah",
  "bar": "bla bla bla",
  "baz": [
    {
      "href": "someid"
    },
    {
      "href": "otherid"
    }
  ],
  "quux": {
    "href": "thisid"
  },
  "whatever": {
    "href": "thatid"
  }
}'
$ curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/datasets/data' -d '
{
  "foo": "argh argh argh",
  "bar": "arg arg arg",
  "baz": [
    {
      "href": "funkyid"
    },
    {
      "href": "thisid"
    }
  ],
  "quux": {
    "href": "hipsterid"
  },
  "whatever": {
    "href": "coolid"
  }
}'
```

I was able to correctly search through the href fields with:

```
$ curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/datasets/data/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "thisid",
      "fields": ["*.href"]
    }
  }
}'
```

So, no need to index them in the `_all` field.

My tests were done on Elasticsearch 5.2.1.

FYI, this is where I found a solution to the question:
[Searching term in subdocuments with elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177276/searching-term-in-subdocuments-with-elasticsearch)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. The difference is that in my case the `href` subfields have `index: not_analyzed`, which is necessary to avoid false positives from similar IDs. I tried `*.href` in the term query, but that doesn't work. I also tried setting `analyzer: keyword` in the `query_string` query, but that didn't work either. Thank you very much for trying, though!

Comment: Could you then dump a sample of the mapping you are using for that index?

That would help reproduce the problem and further help troubleshooting it.

Comment: I tried your suggestion again with 5.1, and I do get search results, but I get too many. I want to search by ID, but the search finds values that are similar, but not identical.